# Complex matrix RREF

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have to find the parametersolution Ax = 0 to this complex matrix. I have used Gauss elimination, but I can't seem to convert into a reduced row echelon form. [image]

Is it necessary to convert it into a RREF to find the parameter solution?
Right now I have the solutions

$$x_1 = -\frac{1}{4} s - \frac{3}{4} t - \frac{1}{4} r $$
$$x_2 = - \frac{5}{8}s +\frac{13}{8}t - \frac{1}{8}r $$

Comment: Yes I made a mistake which I have edited now